# Calling os.walk for multiple root dirs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I note the os.walk API as described here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html
is like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\Me\\Videos')
```

Is there anyway I pass in multiple direcories to this API in a same invocation?

Comment: And what would the result be?

Comment: `for root, dirs, files in itertools.chain(os.walk('/first/path'), os.walk('/second/path')): ...`

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use two for loops?

```
for x in ("c:\\root1", "c:\\root2", "c:\\root3"):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(x):
        pass
```

Or a messy one-liner with `itertools.chain()`:

```
for root, dirs, files in itertools.chain(*[os.walk(x) for x in ("c:\\root1", "c:\\root2", "c:\\root3")]):
    pass
```

Comment: like the idea but it gives... ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: @MoreThanFive The first solution should work just fine, and fixed the one-liner now too.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. But see [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to do what want, not what you asked for.